Bypass Cloudfare with 2 captcha but not getting the sitekey and other info
I will bypass the cloudfare with 2 captcha but I will print the info to check they are getting sitekey and other info but they are not getting the info. what am I doing wrong? this is documentation provided by 2captcha
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', '1b92b965478994ab9539b21b18236d94')

solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path))
driver.get('https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/')
time.sleep(2)

script = '''
const i = setInterval(() => {
    if (window.turnstile) {
        clearInterval(i);
        window.turnstile.render = (a, b) => {
            let p = {
                method: "turnstile",
                key: "YOUR_API_KEY",
                sitekey: b.sitekey,
                pageurl: window.location.href,
                data: b.cData,
                pagedata: b.chlPageData,
                action: b.action,
                userAgent: navigator.userAgent,
                json: 1
            };
            window.turnstileData = {
                sitekey: b.sitekey,
                data: b.cData,
                pagedata: b.chlPageData
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(p));
            window.tsCallback = b.callback;
            return 'foo';
        };
    }
}, 50);
'''


driver.execute_script(script)
time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the script to execute and capture the data

turnstile_data = driver.execute_script("return window.turnstileData;")

if turnstile_data:
    print("Sitekey:", turnstile_data['sitekey'])
    print("Data:", turnstile_data['data'])
    print("Pagedata:", turnstile_data['pagedata'])
else:
    print("Turnstile data not captured.")


is that a private api key you just shared to the world?

I will change these key at any time
